# Magento 2.3.1 upgrade issue : Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract::send()

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, smtp

As I have upgraded the magento system version-2.2.3 to version 2.3.1. I am facing the following error during the customer registration registration from front-end.

[image]

I am using [Neklo SMTP](https://store.neklo.com/custom-smtp-extension-for-magento2.html) mailer extension.

I have upgraded magneto version to 2.3.1. This niklo extension is working fine with magento version 2.2.3 version.

Help please to fix this issue. 
Any help would be appriciated !

**Updated the question :**

Comment: Have you redeployed your website also have you run setup upgrade finally why are you using an extension for SMTP? magento 2 comes standard with SMTP functionality

Comment: Yes, I run the setup upgrade command. It was already running with magento version 2.2.3. I have upgrade the php version ie. 7.2.11 as required for magento version 2.3.1 ( ie php 7.1.3 or greator / php 7.2)

Comment: Magneto 2.2.3 does not support php 7.2, it only supports 7.0.13–7.0.x and 7.1.x if you have upgraded to magento 2.3 you need to run setup:upgrade. also magento sure you delete the content of var/di var/cache and ./generation/*

Comment: Yes, I have upgraded the magento version to 2.3 and run the setup:upgrade command.

Comment: If you purchased the extension check that it is the correct version for 2.3 as the listing page does say it is available for your version. if not id suggest contacting there support team